# Intel GS45/Lenovo X200s screen/video issues

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I'm having some screen/video issues with my new Lenovo X200s, running Windows 7 64-bit. You can see the problem here:

[image]

I've installed the latest Intel GS45 chipset drivers, and the latest graphic drivers (updated with windows update).

Turning off Aero fixes the problem, but I would really like to fix this issue, and if it's a hardware problem, I need to return it.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is a driver issue. Have you tried downloading the [official driver](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=17802&ProdId=2991&lang=eng) from Intel direct yet?

Comment: Yes I tried those. Same problem.

Comment: You probably might want to try a Vista based driver then, just to confirm it is not a hardware issue before you send it in to the manufacturer. By the way, a manufacturer might not support the fact that you tried installing a yet-to-be-officially-released Windows version on your notebook. Best to go back with the original OS installed (and problem still there of course).

Comment: I will try installing Vista. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware video chip fault. You can see the same thing on a desktop computer with a video card having a clogged fan or having a faulty chip.